# Check if method implements IDisposable.Dispose with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, aop

Is there a more formal/failsafe way to check whether a `System.Reflection.MethodInfo` refers to a class' implementation of `IDisposable.Dispose` than the following?

```
System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo;
methodInfo = ...; //methodInfo obtaining code here
bool isDisposeMethod = methodInfo.Name == "Dispose";
```

I already know the class implements `IDisposable` and thus that `Dispose` exists, but I'm using a PostSharp aspect that should perform special functionality when `Dispose` is called (compared to any other class method).

Comment: If a class implements `IDisposable`, you are guaranteed that it implements `Dispose` - that's the point of the interface.

Comment: I understand that. I know that `Dispose` exists, but I'm using a PostSharp aspect that should perform special functionality when `Dispose` is called compared to a different function. The PostSharp aspect returns the method signature in a `System.Reflection.MethodInfo`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having:

```
class DisposableObject : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

You can do:

```
Type t = typeof(DisposableObject);

InterfaceMapping m = t.GetInterfaceMap(typeof(IDisposable));
MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("Dispose");

Console.WriteLine(mi == m.TargetMethods[0]); //true
```

So, I suppose that you have the `MethodInfo` for some `Dispose` method in your class (here `mi`, simply through `GetMethod(string)`). Then you'll need to get an [InterfaceMapping Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.interfacemapping.aspx) object for the `IDisposable` implementation in the declaring type (here `DisposableObject`) through [Type.GetInterfaceMap Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfacemap.aspx) . There you have `TargetMethods` referencing the methods really implementing the interface. So, we only need to check whether your reference equals to `m.TargetMethods[0]` as `IDisposable` declares only one method.

From MSDN:

> **InterfaceMapping Structure**
>
> Retrieves the mapping of an interface into the actual methods on a
>   class that implements that interface.
>
> Use the InterfaceMapping structure when a type implements interface
>   methods that use method names other than those specified by the
>   interface, or when a type implements multiple interfaces which have a
>   method with the same name.
>
> To obtain an InterfaceMapping structure, use the Type.GetInterfaceMap
>   method.

---

One remark: if your class could implement `IDisposable` explicitly, then `m.TargetMethods[0]` would reference the explicit implemetation. So, I'm not sure whether there is any way to get it's `MethodInfo` except the `InterfaceMapping` (See [Use Reflection to find Methods that implement explicit interfaces](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2008/10/15/use-reflection-to-find-methods-that-implement-explicit-interfaces.aspx)). This situation could be error prone. Check it for your specific issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not trying to check whether the object implements `IDisposable` - that's just `bool test = myObj is IDispoable` - I'm trying to test whether a specific `MethodInfo` refers to the class' implementation of `IDisposable.Dispose`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've checked it - should be all ok :)

Answer (score 4):

I think the right way is to `GetInterface("IDisposable")` on the type and then get method info based on interface object. Than you should be able to compare method at hand with method returned from interface.

Just checking name is not enough as

- there could be other methods with the same name but different arguments
- interface could be implemented explcitly.

Here is class that shows both issues:

```
class Test : IDisposable
{
   public void Dispose(){}
   public void Dispose(bool flag){}
   void IDisposable.Dispose(){} 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this may work in your case, its not the prettiest code but it will return if your method info comes from an IDisposible class.

```
System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo;
methodInfo = ...; //methodInfo obtaining code here
bool isDisposible = methodInfo.DeclaringType.FindInterfaces(new System.Reflection.TypeFilter((type, filter) => { return type.ToString() == filter.ToString(); }), "System.IDisposable").Any();
```

Not sure if this is what your after.

Comment: This is a great answer too. I've rolled together what both you and Konstantin Vasilcov have put together into:
`bool isDisposible = methodInfo.DeclaringType.GetInterfaceMap(typeof(IDisposable)).TargetMethods.Where(x => x == methodInfo).Any();`

Comment: You can drop the "Where" clause in the method you have above and just use:

`bool isDisposible = methodInfo.DeclaringType.GetInterfaceMap(typeof(IDisposable)).TargetMethods.Any(x => x == methodInfo);`